# Unix/Mac [bash/c api]: detect if a given path points to a file on a removable device

Tags: macos, unix, filesystems, usb-storage

Is there a *nix command or C api that will tell the type of the storage device given the path to the file (resolving the mounts, symlinks, etc)? I need to find out whether the file lives on a removable device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether find is sufficient to reveal the storage device:

```
find /path/to/your/file.xml -printf "%F"
```

from the manpage:

```
 %F     Type of the filesystem the file is on; this value can be used for -fstype.
```

Another idea is 'stat'

```
stat /home/stefan/.shosts  
  File: `/home/stefan/.shosts'
  Size: 12          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 807h/2055d  Inode: 89647       Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/  stefan)   Gid: ( 1000/  stefan)
Access: 2011-04-11 10:24:21.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2011-03-30 14:45:29.000000000 +0200
Change: 2011-03-30 14:46:03.000000000 +0200
```

There is a line 'Device:' but I don*t know what to do about it. Maybe you find out?

Comment: Device: is a 16 bit integer.  The upper 8 bits are the device major and the lower 8 bits are the device minor.  These can be compared to the major/minor numbers on the nodes in /dev to find the device name that the file is on.

Comment: @Matt: On Linux, the major number is 12 bits and minor is 20 bits.

Comment: @grawity Not on my Linux it isn't

Comment: @Matt: Well, I just did `mknod foo c 4095 1048575` on a last year's kernel (2.6.32-linode). Can't speak for people stuck with 2.4, of course.

Comment: @grawity that may well be, but the Device: entry in stat is still 16 bits.  stat[0] >> 8 = major.  stat[0] & 0xFF = minor.  Otherwise device 2055 (as in the example above) would be major 0 minor 2055...  not quite right, is it?  Linux may be _capable_ of having device major and minors in bigger bits, but I don't think you can have a block device over minor 255.

Comment: @Matt: The st_dev field does not have a strictly defined size - it's declared as a dev_t, which depends on the actual environment. That's why one should use major() and minor() macros rather than hardcode byte offsets. Both stat and ls use stat() as can be proved by strace, and ls copes fine with large numbers.

Comment: @grawity I absolutely agree - but in the specific example above it would appear that an 8 bit minor is in use.

Answer (score 1):

Some *nix implementations might have a cool tool, but it wouldn't be too hard to use mount(1) output to correlate a file and its filesystem:

```
mfe@inker:/home/mfe$ mount
...
/media/WINXP_PRO_SP1 on /dev/dsk/c4t0d0s2 read only/nosetuid/nodevices/noglobal/maplcase/joliet/traildot/dev=14c0002 on Thu Apr  7 07:39:29 2011
```

Giveaways in the mount name aside, any file I find under /media/WINXP_PRO_SP1 has go to be on the DVD-ROM.

Comment: Just a warning: `mount(1)` output is indended for humans. Do *not* parse it. Use `/proc/self/mounts` or `/proc/self/mountinfo` if the detection is to be put in a script.

Comment: Ah. We don't have that feature in Solaris.

Comment: There's still `/etc/mtab`, which uses the same format as `/proc/self/mounts`.

Comment: @grawity - /etc/mnttab, I'm sure you meant.

Answer (score 1):

If `hal` is installed, you could e.g. scrape `lshal`'s output.